# How to update a column for list of values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe and  I want update a value of a column of a dataframe for specific set of data. How can this be done.I have around 20000 records to be updated.

**Sample Input**

```
Id  Registered
345     Y
678     N
987     N
435     N
2345    Y
123     N
679     N
```

I want to update the Registered column to Y when I give Set of Id numbers . How this can be done
I want to change the Registered column of 678,124,435  to Y . How this can this can done when for a large list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a mask generated with `isin` to index `df`'s `Registered` column and set values accordingly.

```
df.loc[df['Id'].isin(ids), 'Registered'] = 'Y'
df

     Id Registered
0   345          Y
1   678          Y
2   987          N
3   435          Y
4  2345          Y
5   123          N
6   679          N
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, the IDs should be passed as  a list right.

Comment: @Rahulrajan Bit late to answer but any container (Series, list, array, etc) will work, not just a list.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can using `where`/`mask`

```
ids=[678,124,435]    
df.Registered=df.Registered.where(df.Id.isin(ids),'Y')
```

Or,

```
df.Registered=df.Registered.where(df.Id.isin(ids),'Y')
```

```
df

     Id Registered
0   345          Y
1   678          N
2   987          Y
3   435          N
4  2345          Y
5   123          Y
6   679          Y
```